# How to give check out and check in access for particular user of a group in TFS

Tags: tfs, permissions, active-directory, user-permissions

There is some group, say contributors, and I want to give check out access to only a specific individual in that group. How to go about this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Groups by their very definition represent a 'container' for users with the same privileges.

You will need to remove the user from the group (or disable the group inheiritance) and assign him explictly or in a new group with the privileges you need assigned.